# How do I remove the line break between two <input> tags?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the line break between two `<input>` tags so that two buttons will display on the same line?

```
<td colspan="1" style="width:1%;padding-left:50px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <input type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;" value="Edit" />
        <input type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnDel" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;" value="Del" />
        @*<button type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;">Edit</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btnDel" id="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:50px;">Del</button>*@
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{
  display:inline-block
}

input,button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
 <td colspan="1" style="width:1%;padding-left:50px;">
        <div>
            <input  type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;" value="Edit" />
            <input  type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnDel" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;" value="Del" />
        <button type="submit" name="btnEdit" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:50px;">Edit</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btnDel"  id="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:50px;">Del</button>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: While working with bootstrap `style="white-space: nowrap;"` worked for me after setting to parent div

Answer (score 2):

The `<input>` and `<button>` elements are inline (inline-block) level by default - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), so they should be aligned next to each other, and there is no `<br>` between them in your code snippet.

As far I as see the problem is likely to be the `width:1%` on the container `<td>`, which makes it to not have enough room for the buttons to grow. The answer is simple: **increase** the container's width. Although, you can also use `white-space: nowrap;` if necessary.

Side note, **ID** must be unique on a page. You use `id=btnEdit` and `id=btnDel` multiple times there, it's likely to cause trouble later, so better to fix that too.